# AttributeError: NoneType for lxml parse getroot method

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, lxml

I am trying to scrap a website using lxml and mechanize, and I got an error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'**

After some check I found `html` returned None.

The funny part is, this code works on other websites, only failed to work this particular website (http://www.selangortimes.com)

```
url = 'http://www.selangortimes.com'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)')]
br.open(url)
resp = br.response()
html = lxml.html.parse(resp).getroot()
link_targets = [link.attrib.get('href') for link in html.xpath(expr)]
```

Appreciate your help :)

**Update:**
An example of a working website using the above code - http://www.themalaysianinsider.com

Comment: It seems to me, that this site is just ugly. As far as I know, mechanize does not handle any javascript. The None might result as a consequence.

Comment: The issue is `lxml.html.parse().getroot()` failed to return document to `resp`. When I debug the response of mechanize, mechanize was able to retrieve the entire html document.

Comment: The problem may be that the page retrieved from (http://www.selangortimes.com) starts with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character (`\uFEFF`) and older versions of *lxml* were known to no be able to handle this correctly. However I have just tested your code with *lxml* **2.3.6** and it parsed the retrieved page correctly.

Comment: Thanks @PedroRomano for the tips, however it still doesn't work :) Do you get any error on html.xpath(expr), where xpath not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following slightly revised version of the code you have posted, using **lxml 2.3.6** and **mechanize 0.2.5** produces a list of all the `href` attributes in `<a>` elements at the `http://www.selangortimes.com` url. **Note** concerning your latest comment that you have to `import lxml.html`.

```
import mechanize
import lxml.html

url = 'http://www.selangortimes.com'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)')]
br.open(url)
resp = br.response()
html = lxml.html.parse(resp).getroot()
link_targets = [link.attrib.get('href') for link in html.xpath('//a')]
print(link_targets)
```